# Python - Unable to import local library

Tags: python, scrapy

I have a scrapy crawler, I wan to use a local library in my crawler.

So, here is my directory model :

[image]

There is two important files db/base.py and /crawler/spiders/adilisik.py

here is base.py

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

Base = declarative_base()

engine = create_engine("mysql+pymysql://xxx:yyy@localhost/test-db")
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()
```

here is some lines from adilisik.php

```
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
    import hashlib
    import re
    import scrapy

    from crawler.db.base import Base

    class AdilisikSpider(scrapy.Spider):
        name = "adilisik"
        allowed_domains = ['adl.com.tr']
        start_urls = ['http://adl.com.tr']
        urls = set()


        def __init__(self, retailer='', *args, **kwargs):
            super(AdilisikSpider, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        def parse(self, response):
.....
.....
```

But I'm not able make this code work.

this line breaks my code.

```
from crawler.db.base import Base
```

I'm getting this error :

```
    from crawler.db.base import Base
ImportError: No module named 'crawler.db'
Could not load spiders from module 'crawler.spiders'. Check SPIDER_MODULES setting
```

What I am doing wrong?

**Edit 1**:

After [Moinuddin Quadri's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41914833/2063361) I have created **init**.py in crawler directory and renamed the crawler directory. But now I'm getting the error below

```
ImportError: No module named 'crawler.settings'
```

Comment: if i read the dir tree correctly, for the settings.py file the import command would be `import crawler.spiders.settings`, if you want the import it to the __imit__.py in the crawler directory

Answer (score 1):

`__init__.py` is missing in your **crawler** directory. Add an empty `__init.__.py` and then you will be able to import `crawler.db` module.

Also, note that you have two directories as `crawler` (+ one more which is your project). Rename one of the directory else you might be facing more errors related to import.

Comment: Please check Edit 1, your suggestion unfortunately didn't fix my problem.

Comment: It is a new error (separate), possibly related to missing `settings.py` in project. I am not familiar with `scrapy`. So I won't be able to provide much help to you. But posting the new error as a separate question with full stack-trace might increase your chance of getting the solution

Comment: BTW I think it would be a very common issue as it is related to setting up the new project. Googling this error will help you resolve it